# Does Caliburn.Micro play nicely with user controls?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I'm a novice WPF programmer. I'm trying to add some structure to my code: both User Controls and MVVM.

Researching here, I've found that [people recommend Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913946/looking-for-the-wpf-mvvm-framework). On the other hand, I've found some complaints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014196/using-caliburn-micro-binding-feature-on-an-inner-user-control) and [elsewhere](http://nosuchblogger.com/post/151/caliburnmicro-and-custom-usercontrols) about Caliburn.Micro not playing nicely with UserControls.

So my question is: **Does Caliburn.Micro play nicely with User Controls?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, `Caliburn.Micro` plays nicely with user controls. It's an opinionated framework, but not to the point of forcing you down a particular development path. As the answers to the linked questions suggest, you can always use plain old WPF binding if you have any particular issues.

In fact, I wouldn't let those two links deter you at all, the first is describing a way of binding separate properties to a single user control, and the solution is valid. A better solution would probably be to use an `ItemsControl` with a custom `DataTemplate`, and then create a collection of DTOs on his view model which contain the property names and values.

The second link is stating how if you create a view (`UserControl`) and create an instance of the view in XAML, and you wish to bind it to a view model, then that is called view first, and you have to tell Caliburn.Micro where the view model is to bind to:

```
<UserControl ...
   cal:Bind.Model="EasyPlayer.MediaControl.NowPlayingViewModel" />
```

So, this conceptually can be thought of as a viewmodel/view rather than a UserControl with dependency properties etc.

In fact, you'll find when you use Caliburn.Micro, you'll probably use less and less `UserControl`s to perform view composition. This is because it is very easy to create reusable pieces of UI using view models, views, and the view model first approach.

When you have a `ContentControl` in a view with the same name as a view model property on your parent view model, then Caliburn.Micro will locate the view of the corresponding view model, inject it into the `ContentControl`, and bind up the view/view model.

For example:

```
public class MyParentViewModel : Screen
{
  public MenuViewModel MenuViewModel { get; set; }

  public DetailsViewModel DetailsViewModel { get; set; }

  public MyParentViewModel()
  {
    this.MenuViewModel = new MenuViewModel();
    this.DetailsViewModel = new DetailsViewModel();
  }
}

<Grid> 
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MenuViewModel" />
  <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="DetailsViewModel" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: starting out with caliburn and just came across your very helpful post - ... could expand a bit on now using usercontrols as much ... afaics a view is going to be a usercontrol isn't it? thxvm

Comment: Yes, with Caliburn.Micro you won't use user controls in the sense of user controls with dependency properties, instantiating the controls directly from another user control/window etc.

Comment: ok ... but you'll still house, say, a grid in a usercontrol (with all the custom behaviour in the viewmodel/xaml) and get that dynamically loaded into a ContentControl via Caliburn.Micro? (Just want to check I'm not missing something). Thx very much again.

Comment: Yes that's correct, or you could use a Window if you were using the window manager and wanted to control the window properties declaratively

Comment: Excellent. Thx very much. Sorry, but as I say new to this. Could you explain (or perhaps point to a link to explain) a bit more about what you mean wrt using windows? Thx again.

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.window.aspx and http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/

Comment: Can also use the DI container and include `MenuViewModel` as a ctor arg in `ParentViewModel` to automatically wire them up.