# WPF Nested User Controls and MVVM (esp. Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I’m taking a lot of worry selecting an MVVM framework to convert to. One of the major considerations is support for User Controls and nested user controls as my main page today has a user control that contains nested user controls.

The author of Catel [highlights lack of support for nested user contorls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129920/Catel-Part-3-of-n-The-MVVM-Framework#nested) as a major disadvantage of other platforms (inc. Caliburn.Micro)

So my question is: **Doesn't Caliburn.Micro support nested user controls?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro doesn't place any restrictions on the types of mechanisms you use for developing your user interface. It isn't a requirement to use Caliburn.Micro's conventions, you can still be explicit with your bindings when required.

If you are using user controls to reuse user interface code during view composition, then Caliburn.Micro provides an alternative technique for this too, using view model properties and `ContentControl`s.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580325/does-caliburn-micro-play-nicely-with-user-controls) for an example.

Comment: That's a great question you linked to ;).  However, how does it work with nested user controls?

Comment: Are you using nested user controls purely for view composition? If so, you would use the same technique as shown in that question on your child view models. i.e. they would also have public properties that are other view model instances, and you would use ContentControl's on their respective views to reuse views and presentation logic.