# Add view directly to xaml with Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm still experimenting a bit with Caliburn Micro and I can't seem to find a way to directly add a view to a xaml without adding another `ContentControl` with a property in the viewmodel behind it.

I can place this: `<views:TheView ... />` in the xaml but then it can't find the target actions so it seems it doesn't find the viewmodel behind the view.

Is it possible to directly declare a view in a xaml without a `ContentControl`, and how?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to tell Caliburn to bind the view model to a user control.

In the definition of "TheView" are you able to add the following line to the UserControl element:

```
cal:Bind.Model="TheViewModel"
```

So it will look similar to:

```
<UserControl  x:Class="Example.Views.TheView" 
              cal:Bind.Model="Example.ViewModels.TheViewModel" ...
```

While looking into this I did find this answer to another StackOverflow question:
[Does Caliburn.Micro play nicely with user controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580325/does-caliburn-micro-play-nicely-with-user-controls)